# Web Application writes events to event log only from localhost

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, event-log, application-pool, custom-errors

We have an ASP.net MVC Application deployed to Win Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.

The problem is that application stopped writing events to event log
when we changed App Pool framework to 4.

But application still writes warnings and errors to event log from localhost.

Probably this section of our *web.config* has to be changed.

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/" mode="RemoteOnly" />
  <compilation debug="false">
```

Also our App pool settings:
[image: Our App Pool Settings]

Comment: Are you talking about 'standard' events such as application startup / shutdown, or custom events written to the log by your code in the MVC app?

Comment: standard events - errors and warnings, not only application startup/ shutdown, but all unhalted errors too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system.web/healthMonitoring settings.  I used the configuration editor inside of the IIS manager to add a setting to log events to the event log when any request failed.  The IIS manager generated the following script:

```
appcmd.exe set config "TestSite" -section:system.web/healthMonitoring /+"rules.[eventName='Request Processing Errors',name='Request Processing Errors Default',profile='Default',provider='EventLogProvider']"
```

You will have to replace the `"TestSite"` above with the name of the site you want to modify.

Hopefully, if this doesn't fix your problem, it will at least get you on the correct path.

Comment: I ran this script and windows applied configuration changes to "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MySite". But In Windows Log ->Application section still no events from MySite. Even more  - no events logged even if raise events from localhost.